# Converting C# ExtNet DirectMethod implementation to VB.NET

Tags: c#, ajax, vb.net, ext.net

How do I converst the below code to VB.NET?

```
[DirectMethodProxyID(IDMode = DirectMethodProxyIDMode.Alias, Alias = "UC")]
public partial class AliasID : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    [DirectMethod]
    public void HelloUserControl()
    {
        X.Msg.Alert("Message", "Hello from UserControl").Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<DirectMethodProxyID(IDMode := DirectMethodProxyIDMode.[Alias], [Alias] := "UC")> _
Public Partial Class AliasID
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
    <DirectMethod> _
    Public Sub HelloUserControl()
        X.Msg.Alert("Message", "Hello from UserControl").Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Use this in future for simple code conversion http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/